# Howto install biber on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation, latex

I have solved it. It is  necessary to install the latest binary from the ["development"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/development/) folder, extract the only file called "biber" and copy it to "/usr/bin".

The binary of the latest stable version [1.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/1.0/) will not work though and show this error.

```
slazer@peter:~/Downloads$ tar xvf "biber-linux_x86_64(2).tar.gz" 
biber
slazer@peter:~/Downloads$ ./biber
data source /tmp/par-736c617a6572/cache-fb3144567cd1381b403b18600c1ec4b232b2c018/inc/lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml not found in .
Compilation failed in require at Biber/Utils.pm line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber/Utils.pm line 20.
Compilation failed in require at Biber/Internals.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber/Internals.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 22) line 2.
    ...propagated at /usr/local/perl/lib/5.14.1/base.pm line 94.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at script/biber line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script/biber line 20.
```

What could be the problem? I have 64 bit Linux.

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone has trouble with more recent versions, the following worked for me, for Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty):

First, I completed a ['vanilla' install of TeXLive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) as per the instructions in the link.

Then simply:

```
sudo apt-get -y install biber
```

This currently installs version 1.8.

Everything appears to work fine with this, including AucTeX.

Comment: Works even for 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

To install Biber, you can do so from the Ubuntu Software Center.  By clicking below:

[image]

Comment: This is, however, only for Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal). When I click it, the Ubuntu software center does not find the package.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 12.04 uses biblatex version 1.7-1; you can verify this by running:

`apt-cache show biblatex`

According to [the biber documentation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/1.0/documentation/biber.pdf/download), the last biber release to support biblatex 1.7 is biber 0.9.9.

You can download the appropriate version of biber 0.9.9—32bit or 64bit—here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/0.9.9/binaries/Linux/

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no `biber`-package for ubuntu 12.04, you can go ahead and install the one from ubuntu 12.10. It is still available at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/biber/biber_0.9.9+release-1_all.deb. After installing it with `dpkg -i` the dependencies can be pulled via `apt-get -f install`.